# Acceso a archivos mediante PHP con un alias al directorio en el apache

Tags: php, linux, apache

tengo dos dominios que comparten un directorio (ejemplo: /img ) para no duplicar ese directorio tengo creado un Alias con el apache:

Alias /img /dominio_1.com/img/
....

desde el navegador accedo sin problemas al directorio img

**www.dominio_2.com/img/imagen.jpg**

pero desde php no puedo acceder a ese archivo

```
$img = file_get_contents('/img/imagen.jpg');
```

Warning... failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Supongo que será cosa de permisos, pero todavía no encontré una solución

Answer (score 1):

Un alias de apache afecta a la navegación web, pero no a la ruta de los ficheros. Para acceder a los contenidos a través del sistema de ficheros, prueba creando un enlace simbólico de la carpeta de dominio_1 en dominio_2

```
ln -s {rutaDirectorioOrigen} {rutaDirectorioDestino}
```

O bien puedes acceder a los ficheros a través de su url de la siguiente manera

```
$img = file_get_contents('http://midominio_2.com/img/imagen.jpg');
```

De esta manera no necesitas crear nada a nivel de sistema de ficheros, pero tendrás que habilitar la configuración de php para que te permita hacerlo. En concreto la opción [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/es/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Comment: yo tb estaba valorando el enlace simbólico, supongo  que acabaré haciendo eso ya que la segunda opción (la que uso mientras ;) )  ralentiza un poco el proceso. Gracias :)

Comment: Ciertamente, en términos de rendimiento, es preferible el acceso local a los ficheros. En ese caso, la opción #1 es más adecuada.